# How to only watch for new events?

Tags: web3js

My code:

```
mainContract.events.Transfer({
    fromBlock: 0
}, function (error, event) {
    console.log(event)
})
```

This method returns all the past events (I guess because of that `fromBlock: 0`)

Now my question is how can I set this to only watch for new events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of zero you can use "latest", other commonly used block is "pending".

See [web3's documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) for a better explanation.